# Capture iframe csp/sandbox errors

Tags: iframe, error-handling, cypress, content-security-policy

I'm writing Cypress tests to validate iframe security policies around sandbox & CSP permissions. I have disabled `allow-modals` and calls to alert and others fail as expected the following Chrome generated error message: `VM271 about:srcdoc:1 Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.` Great, as expected.

Now I need to build a Cypress test to prove that the behavior on the iframe is correct. I was initially going to do this by spying on the iframe/window's console.error and checking for a call with the above error message. This did not work. I have wrapped the window, iframe, and cypress environment error handlers and `console.error` functions with a spy and none of them are called when Chrome logs the above 'ignore alert' error message. I also wrapped the iframe `window.alert()` in a spy and it is still called (as expected) but the browser's alert modal doesn't show (as expected because it's being ignored by chrome).

Is there a way to catch the browser's 'special' error log here? If it's not being logged through the browser window or iframe window elements, how is it being logged?

Iframe:
`<iframe><script>alert('test');</script></iframe>`

Cypress:

```js
let iframeWindow;
let spyErrorIframe;
cy.get('iframe').then(($iframe) => {
  iframeWindow = $iframe[0].contentWindow;
  function errorHandler(...args) {
    console.log('~~~ iframe');
    return iframeWindow.console.error(...args);
  }
  spyErrorIframe = cy.spy(errorHandler);
  iframeWindow.addEventListener('error', spyErrorIframe);
  iframeWindow.onerror = spyErrorIframe;
  cy.spy(iframeWindow.console, 'log');
  cy.spy(iframeWindow.console, 'error');
  cy.spy(iframeWindow, 'alert');
});

let mainWindow;
let spyErrorWindow;
cy.window().then((win) => {
  mainWindow = win;
  function errorHandler(...args) {
    console.log('~~~ window');
    return iframeWindow.console.error(...args);
  }
  spyErrorWindow = cy.spy(errorHandler);
  mainWindow.addEventListener('error', spyErrorWindow);
  mainWindow.onerror = spyErrorWindow;
  cy.spy(win, 'alert');
  cy.spy(win.console, 'log');
  cy.spy(win.console, 'error');
});

cy.wait(GENERIC_TIMEOUT + 1000).then(() => {
  console.log('~~~ iframe console.error', iframeWindow.console.error.getCalls()); // no calls
  console.log('~~~ window console.error', mainWindow.console.error.getCalls()); // no calls
  console.log('~~~ cypress console.error', console.error.getCalls()); // no calls
  console.log('~~~ iframe error event', spyErrorIframe.getCalls()); // no calls
  console.log('~~~ window error event', spyErrorWindow.getCalls()); // no calls
  console.log('~~~ iframe alert', iframeWindow.alert.getCalls()); // one call as expected
  console.log('~~~ window alert', mainWindow.alert.getCalls()); // no calls
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd try to boil down the problem a bit, this works for a simplified web page that just throws a console error.

**Page source**

```html
<body>
  <iframe
    id="inlineFrameExample"
    title="Inline Frame Example"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="./frame1.html"
  >
  </iframe>
</body>
```

**Inner frame source**

```html
<h1>iframe</h1>
<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.error('Catch me')
  }, 500)
</script>
```

**Test code**

I've added [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) in case there's some delay in loading the frame content.

Just focused on `console.error` for purpose of this demo, but should work with other property spies for `console.log` and `window.alert`.

Using an alias for the spy would be better in a real-world example as `cy.wait()` may require different timing depending on external conditions (network speed, CI platform).

```js
import 'cypress-iframe';

it('tests the iframe console.error', () => {

...


let iframeWindow;
let spyErrorIframe;

cy.enter().then(getBody => {
  getBody()
  .its('0.ownerDocument.defaultView')
  .then(win => {
    iframeWindow = win 

    function errorHandler(...args) {
      console.log('~~~ iframe');                           // log appears in console
      return iframeWindow.console.error(...args);
    }

    spyErrorIframe = cy.spy(iframeWindow.console, 'error', errorHandler)
      .as('spyErrorIframe')   
 
  })
})

// Using alias should means you don't have to wait
cy.get('@spyErrorIframe')
  .should('have.been.calledOnceWith', 'Catch me')           // passes

cy.wait(1000).then(() => {
  // one call logged
  console.log('~~~ iframe error event', spyErrorIframe.getCalls());     
})
```

Ref: [Spies, Stubs & Clocks](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/commands/spies-stubs-clocks.html#spy-retries)

Comment: I'm having no issue catching errors around the iframe. This issue seems to specifically come about when using sandboxed iframes. The browser enforces iframe sandboxing by blocking the execution of the alert function and outputting an error message to the console. This specific edge case, blocked window.alert, is not picked up by spying on the window, iframe, or global cypress console.error. When you spy on window.alert in the iframe, you'll see calls to the spy but the window alert modal will not show. I'm trying to write a test that verifies the alert modal on the browser window did not show.